# Plot line with color for each segment attribute

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot line with discrete color for each segment component give the following data frame:

```
head(profilo1, 10)
   dx TPI      DEM
1   0   5 2159.219
2   2   5 2157.735
3   4   5 2156.269
4   6   5 2154.752
5   8   5 2153.282
6  10   5 2151.925
7  12   5 2150.660
8  14   3 2149.402
9  16   3 2148.277
10 18   2 2147.149
```

`dx` & `DEM` are x and y, while `TPI` is the color attribute (span from 1:10) I need to link to color.  I wish to use some color table from `RColorBrewer` (eg. Paired).
While I'm looking around for solution, I find useful this

```
color_paired = brewer.pal(n = 10, "Paired")

plot(profilo1$dx, profilo1$DEM,t='p', 
     xlab = "Profile distance (m)", 
     ylab = "Elevation (m.s.l.m)",
     col = color_paired[profilo1$TPI], cex= .3)
```

But I'll prefer line to point.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by first making a blank plot and then using the `segements` function.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
color_paired=brewer.pal(n = 10, "Paired")

plot(profilo1$dx,profilo1$DEM, xlab="Profile distance (m)",
     ylab="Elevation (m.s.l.m)", type="n")
segments(head(profilo1$dx, -1), head(profilo1$DEM, -1), 
    profilo1$dx[-1], profilo1$DEM[-1], 
    col=color_paired[head(profilo1$TPI, -1)])
```

[image: Colored segments]

### Data

```
profilo1 = read.table(text="dx TPI      DEM
1   0   5 2159.219
2   2   5 2157.735
3   4   5 2156.269
4   6   5 2154.752
5   8   5 2153.282
6  10   5 2151.925
7  12   5 2150.660
8  14   3 2149.402
9  16   3 2148.277
10 18   2 2147.149",
header=TRUE)
```